# Angular $compile on scope with ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that uses the `$compile` service to generate a template. It won't generate the select options using `ng-options` or `ng-repeat`, even though I clearly have the `users` array set in my scope. Why doesn't this work? This just gives me a blank `<select>` field with no options.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("selectForm", [
  '$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.users = [
          { id: 1, name: "User 1" },
          { id: 2, name: "User 2" }
        ];

        element.on('click', function(e) {

          var selectHtml = $compile('\
            <select\
              class="col-lg-2 form-control"\
              ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users">\
            </select>\
          ')(scope);

          $(element).html(selectHtml);
        });

      }
    }
  }

]);
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap your click event code in a scope.$apply.

Comment: Can you show your example in Fiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something to change in your code to make it work:

- `<select>` works only when you also supply `ng-model`
- Wrap your code inside `scope.$apply`.
- Call `element.off("click")` to unsubscribe to the event to avoid flickering.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Agz5P/)

Comment: smh..."works only when you also supply ng-model"...it got me, your comment helped, thanks